# inserting value to a binary tree but produces none value

Tags: python

```
def build_tree(entry, left, right):
    return [entry, left, right]

def entry(tree):
    return tree[0]

def left_branch(tree):
    return tree[1]

def right_branch(tree):
    return tree[2]

def make_empty_tree():
    return []

t1 = build_tree(2,build_tree(1,make_empty_tree(),make_empty_tree()),build_tree(3,make_empty_tree(),make_empty_tree()))
```

These are the functions that I have currently defined for the binary tree.
i wish to insert a value to the right branch of T1 using the following function.

```
def insert_tree(x, tree):
    if tree == []: 
        tree.append(x)
        return tree
    else:
        if x <= entry(tree): 
            return insert_tree(x , left_branch(tree))
        else: 
            return insert_tree(x , right_branch(tree))
```

however, this gives me `[5]` instead of the expected 
`[2, [[1],[],[]], [[3],[],[5]]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `insert_tree` with:

```
insert_tree(5, t1)
```

then `t1` would become:

```
[2, [1, [], []], [3, [], [5]]]
```

but this is not a well-formed tree because the tree of 5 should have two empty child nodes as well. You should instead initialize the tree by extending the list with an additional two empty lists:

```
def insert_tree(x, tree):
    if tree == []:
        tree.extend([x, [], []])
        return tree
    if x <= entry(tree):
        return insert_tree(x , left_branch(tree))
    else:
        return insert_tree(x , right_branch(tree))
```

so that `insert_tree(5, t1)` would make `t1`:

```
[2, [1, [], []], [3, [], [5, [], []]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you call `t1 = insert_tree(t1, 5)`?
The problem is that `insert_tree` only returns in the special case of the argument `tree == []`. Return the tree at the end instead.

```
def insert_tree(x, tree):
    if tree == []: 
        tree.append(x)
    else:
        if x <= entry(tree): 
            insert_tree(x , left_branch(tree))
        else: 
            insert_tree(x , right_branch(tree))
    return tree
```

Btw, your functions does not constitute a valid definition of a tree, for example `left_branch(make_empty_tree())` would fail.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def insert_tree(x, tree):
    if is_empty_tree(tree):
        return build_tree(x, tree, tree)
    def is_leaf(item):
        return type(item) == int
    if is_leaf(left_branch(tree)):
        if x <= entry(tree):
            return build_tree(left_branch(tree), x, None)
        else:
            return build_tree(left_branch(tree), None, x)
    elif is_leaf(left_branch(tree)) == False:
        return insert_tree(x, left_branch(tree))
    elif is_leaf(right_branch(tree)):
        if x <= right_branch(tree):
            return build_tree(right_branch(tree), x, None)
        else:
            return build_tree(right_branch(tree), None, x)
    elif is_leaf(right_branch(tree)) == False:
        return insert_tree(x, right_branch(tree))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).